# How to find the values of a at which $y$ is increasing?

Tags: functions

I don't know how to solve this one and the question is:

Find the values of a at which $y = x^3 + ax^2 + 3x + 1$.

My solution is:

$y'= 3x^2 + 2ax + 3$

I know that if $y' \ge 0$, $y$ should be always increasing. I don't know how to make it true. Please help and explain and thank you in advance!

Edit: i saw another solution but cannot understand it.

D/4 = a^2 - 9

What does the D stand for and why divide it by 4. Also where does the a^2 - 9 come from?

Also, how do you write exponents?

Answer (score 2):

Try writing it in a different form:

$$y'=3(x^2+2ax/3+1)=3((x+a/3)^2-a^2/9+1)$$
Since $(x+a/3)^2$ is always non-negative, we need
$$-a^2/9+1 > 0$$
so
$$a^2 < 9\to -3<a<3$$
so the answer is (assuming strictly increasing)
$$a\in (-3,3)$$

Answer (score 0):

Well, you made the first right step.

$$y^{'} = 3x^2 + 2ax + 3$$

Now You need to know which values for $a$ satisfy $3x^2 + 2ax + 3 \geq 0$

Now $$ 2ax \geq -3 -3x^2$$

so

$$ax \geq \frac{-3x^2}{2} - \frac{3}{2}$$

Now you should do some effort to figure out what are the possible values for $a$